# statsmodel's r2 showing NaN

Tags: python, statsmodels

statsmodel's rsquared calculation is returning puzzling result. rmse sometimes return nan or `ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes`  even when the X and y have the exact same number of rows.

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
nobs = 100
X = np.random.random((nobs, 2))
X = sm.add_constant(X)
beta = [1, .1, .5]
e = np.random.random(nobs)
y = np.dot(X, beta) + e
mdl = sm.QuantReg(y, X).fit(q=0.5)
mdl.rsquared # -> this will show nan
```

I've read elsewhere that one cannot use scikit-learn's r2_score to calculate r2 on sm result. however if mdl.rsquared is the only way to go and the model only fit on training, then wouldn't training and testing set have the exact same r2?

Comment: What's the meaning of rsquared when estimating a quantile? rsquared is set to nan because it is inherited but doesn't apply to quantreg.

Comment: @Josef it could also show nan on ols. i was wondering it's due to too many variables (more than the number of records) or other reasons

Comment: IIRC: In OLS, rsquared should be nan only in some corner cases where the dependent variable has zero variance. In QuantReg the nan is hardcoded for rsquared.